# PHP Select query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello All,

```
       for()
          {
            SELECT * from x union select * from y union select * from z
          }
```

I added union to all other queries which comes,when for loop runs but in my last line ,i've to remove the UNION ,how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Could you try to explain a little more clearly please?

Comment: What language is that? PHP? SQL? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much information to work with, but I'm assuming you're starting with an array of query strings. If so, try this:

```
$queries = array();
$queries[] = "SELECT * FROM x";
$queries[] = "SELECT * FROM y";
$queries[] = "SELECT * FROM z";

$query = implode(" UNION ", $queries);

// $query now contains "SELECT * FROM x UNION SELECT * FROM y UNION SELECT * FROM z"
```

Comment: :I want to remove the union only in the ueries[n] means the last line of the total no of queries.

Comment: It's still very unclear to me what you're trying to do. Could you edit your question and include more detail and an expected result?